# Magento 2 compile error

Tags: magento2

Previous version
Magento 2.4.5 and php 7.4

After upgrade php version 8.1 getting compile error
< 1 sec 117.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected token "<"#0 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#1 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#2 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#3 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#4 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()

After debug the code in /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php file its getting error related with private function.
private function includeClass(string $className, string $fileItemPath): bool
{
if (!class_exists($className)) {
// phpcs:ignore
require_once $fileItemPath;
return true;
}
return false;
}

So I remove the function and write the code directly called function. But I have seen same error is getting at compile time which define at private function.
private function extract(\RecursiveIteratorIterator $recursiveIterator)

After that didnt get any solution then downgrade the PHP version 8.1 to 7.4. But this time again getting following error.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:1146
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(806): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->splitStringByWidth()
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(776): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRenderException()
#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(132): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderException()
#3 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->Symfony\Component\Console{closure}()
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(113): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#5 /usr/bin/composer(62): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#6 {main}
thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 1146

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be related to a missing PHP extension. The "mbstring" extension is not enabled in your PHP 7.4 installation.

You can enable this extension by adding this line to your php.ini file

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

Comment: If we will proceed with PHP version 8.1 then how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: You can do it in this same way for php 8.1 also .  I mean just enable the extension